# On Einstein notation with multiple indices

Tags: notation, tensor-calculus

On [Einstein notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) with multiple indices: For example, consider the expression:

$$a^{ij} b_{ij}.$$

Does the notation signify,

$$a^{00} b_{00} + a^{01} b_{01} + a^{02} b_{02} + ... $$

i.e. you sum over every combination of the indices? Or do you sum over the indices at the same time, i.e. they take on the same values:

$$ a^{00} b_{00} + a^{11} b_{11} +... ?$$

Comment: The first case. Sum over each index independently.

Answer (score 7):

Written explicitly, (assuming summation over indices from 0 to 3)

$$a^{ij}b_{ij} = \sum_{i=0}^3 \sum_{j=0}^3 a^{ij}b_{ij}$$

You can expand this to

$$a^{ij}b_{ij} = \sum_{i=0}^3 \left( a^{i0}b_{i0} + a^{i1}b_{i1} + a^{i2}b_{i2} + a^{i3}b_{i3} \right) $$
$$\implies a^{ij}b_{ij} = a^{00}b_{00} + a^{01}b_{01} + a^{02}b_{02} + a^{03}b_{03} + a^{10}b_{10} + a^{11}b_{11} + a^{12}b_{12} + a^{13}b_{13} + a^{20}b_{20} + a^{21}b_{21} + a^{22}b_{22} + a^{23}b_{23} + a^{30}b_{30} + a^{31}b_{31} + a^{32}b_{32} + a^{33}b_{33}$$

Answer (score 2):

You would sum over every combination of indices that match. So the `i` should match, and the `j` should match. For instance, if each is from 1 to 3, you would get:

$a^{11}b_{11}+a^{12}b_{12}+a^{13}b_{13}+a^{21}b_{21}+a^{22}b_{22}+a^{23}b_{23}+a^{31}b_{31}+a^{31}b_{32}+a^{33}b_{33}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do it one at a time:

$$a^{ij}b_{ij} = \sum_{j}a^{ij}b_{ij} = a^{i0}b_{i0}+a^{i1}b_{i1}+(\dots). $$

Then you expand on the other index
$$a^{ij}b_{ij} = a^{i0}b_{i0}+a^{i1}b_{i1}+\dots = (a^{00}b_{00}+b^{10}b_{10}+\dots)+(a^{01}b_{01}+a^{11}b_{11}+\dots)+(\dots).$$

If you write $a^{jj}b_{jj}$, then you will obtain the second sum you wrote, i.e.,

$$a^{jj}b_{jj}=a^{00}b_{00}+a^{11}b_{11}+(\dots).$$

Comment: Ack! $a^{jj}b_{jj}$ is not right, you can't repeat an index more than twice in a term!

Comment: I think the answer was just suggesting what it could mean *if* you wrote that expression, so not really deserving of a downvote imo.

Comment: An answer about correct Einstein summation notation should contain within it correct Einstein summation notation. I have no problem removing the downvote when either the notation is corrected or it's removed as it's tangential to the question. Once it's done, ping me and I'll remove the vote but I don't remember off hand what the correct notation is to edit it myself. I'd rather see it corrected than removed as it's still interesting.

Comment: @tpg2114: you *can* repeat indices twice in one term. It's unfortunate you haven't read, e.g., chapters 7 or 12 of Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler's _Gravitation_ for examples of this "in the wild"...

Comment: @AlexNelson Twice is not the problem, 4 times is the problem. Going through all my books, I have yet to see any that say repeating an index more than 2 times in a term is okay.

Comment: @tpg2114 I was going to write a snarky reply, when I chanced upon introductory undergraduate texts on GR. They agree with you, insisting Einstein convention dictates a pair of summed indices appears once. But -- oddly enough -- graduate GR and mathematics texts do not have this requirement. It appears to be because there is ambiguity if you use the Euclidean summation convention (i.e., sum any pair of indices, even if they're both upstairs or downstairs), which particle physicists are so fond of. It gets worse with fermionic variables, and fibrations!

Comment: @AlexNelson For what it's worth, graduate fluid and structural dynamics books agree with me too :) Can't speak for GR or pure math, but all of my fluids books say 2 is the limit.

Comment: You may want to specify that $a^{jj}b_{jj}$ is not valid Einstein summation notation, and it uses the Euclidean convention.